# Encog neural network training java too slow

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network, encog

I am training a neural network to classify images and it takes too long to finish one iteration... about five minutes and it is still not done. I am using Encog 3.1. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
BasicNetwork network = new BasicNetwork();
        network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(null,true,5625));
        network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(),true,(intIdealCount+5625)/2));
        network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(),true,intIdealCount));
        network.getStructure().finalizeStructure();
```

here is my training codes:

```
final ResilientPropagation train = new ResilientPropagation(network, trainingSet);

        int epoch = 1;

        do {
            train.iteration();
            System.out.println("Epoch #" + epoch + " Error:" + train.getError());
            epoch++;
        } while(train.getError() > 0.01);
```

Any response will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, but am familiar with machine learning and its application to imaging.  It could take a long time...

Comment: Hi, Sorry for OT, but I am starting with encog and I have some things that I do not fully understand. Can I ask you for a little bit of your time an help? If yes, please check my question question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847695/c-sharp-encog-svm-classification-with-my-own-dataset .Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code seems fine, but training can get arbitrary long depending on your data. From the size of your network one can deduce, that you are working with images - now if you have lots of them - even the most efficient implementation will take forever. Encog is quite good piece of code - it by default works on all avaliable cores, but FANN seems to be the fastest library for ANN for now.

You have ~5000 input neurons, assuming that you have ~10 output neurons, you have ~2500 hidden ones. So your network has (5000+1)*2500 + (2500+1)*10 weights (about 12,500,000). Now, assuming that you have N images in your training set - one epoch requires computation (and update) of 12,500,000 * N values. So even if you have just ~200 images it is 2,500,000,000 updates to compute.

There are at least three possible ways:

- Try the FANN library, which is one of the most efficient ones
- Reduce dimensionality of your images using for example PCA (and as a result - reduce the size of the network)
- Are you sure that you need 2500 hidden nodes? It is quite a lot

Comment: how many hidden layers do you suggest? i am working on a skin disease diagnosis via image recognition.

Comment: I suggest as small as possible. Bigger amount not only means longer computation but also more probable overfitting. Simply start with some small one and increase its size if necessary - not the other way around.

Comment: I've never used Encog before - but thats not the full picture. While a big number - thats only 2.5 GigaFLOPs. A (not fancy) core 2 Q6600 can do 38 GigaFLOPs per second. Even assuming a penalty for Java being slower than C/C++ for raw throughput - it should be possible to complete 1 epoch in a reasonable time.

Comment: now I'm getting a better iteration rate... 

about 3 iterations for five mins... I want to ask now if is it alright to use raw single-int rgb value for the image recognition input neuron so i could save memory space or should i use the red, green and blue values as three separate neurons?

Comment: You should rather apply them separately or consider using a greyscale values. Remember also about correct data normalization/scaling.

Comment: +1 for FANN. That's a new one to me, and it looks like I can use its features. Thanks!